# AssertJ AssertThat isEqual taking way too long to return

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, ui-automation, assertj

**Platform**:
IntelliJ IDEA on a mac

**Java**:
openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20+8-LTS, mixed mode)

**AssertJ**
org.assertj:assertj-core:3.16.1

I've scoured several websites, Baeldung, Project Lombok, and the AssertJ website itself, but I'm non the wiser!

It's very simple:  In my java code, I have a stripped down version of one of my tests

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DisplayName("This is just a test of AssertJ")

public class testAssertJ  {

    @Test
    public void assertJTest() {
        assertThat("actualMessage").isEqualTo("actualMessage");
    }
}
```

When executing this code, it' complete in milliseconds, however when I debug it (putting a **breakpoint** on the line containing **assertThat**.) and step over it, then this is where it can take upto 30 seconds to complete!!!

The question is WHY??

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a simple console app (no dependencies other than AssertJ) which *just* performs the assertion? The simpler you can make the repro, the better...

Comment: Is it an Intel Mac or an Apple Silicon?

Comment: Does this happen the first time it is called in the same program, or on each invocation? Maybe loading one of the classes triggers a lot of classloading (and maybe classpath searching?)

Comment: Could you share a full reproducible example? By the way, you are using a rather old version of AssertJ, the latest is 3.25.3. Not that it should make a difference, though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated comments and code.

Comment: Your repro still uses JUnit though - again, are you able to reproduce this in a console app which isn't even using JUnit? (I'd expect AssertJ to work just fine in console apps...)

Comment: Can you be sure that the delay is in the AssertJ code, and not in the IntelliJ debugger itself?